# Services Providers are being called multiple times

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-octane

I'm using Laravel 10 With Octane Swoole and PHP 8.2. In any ServiceProvider I use the register() or boot() method, it's being called 24 times at system startup. Example:

```
public function register(): void
{
    echo "service starting";
}
```

or:

```
public function boot(): void
{
    echo "service starting";
}
```

using any of the methods, it is returning me in the console:

```
service starting
   INFO  Server running…

   Local: http://0.0.0.0:80

   Press Ctrl+C to stop the server
    

INFO service startingservice startingservice startingservice
startingservice startingservice startingservice startingservice 
startingservice startingservice startingservice startingservice 
startingservice startingservice startingservice startingservice 
startingservice startingservice startingservice startingservice
```

It is being called multiple times. Why does it happen?

Answer (score 2):

It's important to note that the register and boot methods should be designed to be idempotent, which means that they can be called multiple times without causing any issues. So, even though the methods may be called multiple times, they should not cause any problems with the operation of your application.

If you're concerned about the number of times the methods are being called, you can use a static property or cache to ensure that the methods are only executed once, regardless of how many times they are called.